# Accessing an array element in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, indexing

On running the following line in Python (vT is an array of floats):

y = np.nonzero(vT < flag)

I get y as:

(array([1939, 1940, 1941, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999], dtype=int64),)

Question: How do I access the first element (i.e. 1939) from this result?

Comment: You can get it the same way you access a list: y[0]

Comment: I tried that, but that gives the same result: array([1939, 1940, 1941, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999], dtype=int64). In fact y[0][0] gave 1939

Comment: OK, that can't be both y and y[0], but I suspect that vT is a 2d array. You can confirm this by checking vT.shape

Comment: vT.shape = (10000,)

Comment: Ah, OK, I see what is happening. According to the docs, np.nonzero returns a tuple of arrays. Since vT is one dimensional, it returns a tuple of one array, but to access the array you first need to take the first element of the tuple with y[0], then to access the first element of that array you need another [0] ie y[0][0].

Comment: So y must actually look like (array([1939, 1940, 1941, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999], dtype=int64),)

Comment: in fact, you are correct. y is (array([1939, 1940, 1941, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999], dtype=int64),), my mistake! Making this correction to my question....

Comment: the result look like a tuple, look at the far right the is a "," ence the need of [0][0] to access the first element